# В чем подвох? Подсчитать количество просмотров баннера

Tags: php, mysql

Дали тестовое задание по *подсчету количества просмотров* **одного** баннера, который включается на страницу как

```
<img src="image.php">
```

Насколько я понимаю, подвох в том как реализовать этот самый подсчет наименее затратно. У меня из идей memcache, mysql и файлы. При чем, я планирую реализовать это на mysql, но до сих пор в сомнениях. Может вы что-то подскажете? Возможно я просто все усложняю?

Comment: просто добавляете в таблицу запись после каждого обращения к файлу, а потом делайте запрос на вывод `count` этих записей, самый простой вариант

Comment: что есть просмотр баннера? просмотром можно считать просто загрузку страницы с этим баннером?

Comment: @Skywave да, именно загрузку страницы с этим баннером (не клик)

Comment: в файл писать наверно самое быстрое. быстрее чем инициализировать соединение с бд. но не самое удобное. Главное, чтобы вашу картинку браузер не закешировал xD А может быть и надо, чтобы кешировал. Тут надо подумать над поведением

Comment: как поставили задачу так ее и решай. Используй базу для хранения и сделай так чтобы один и тот же пользователь обновляя страницу не увеличивал счетчик. Скорее всего ты все усложняешь...